# Тесты с ActiveRecord: Как разрабатывать быстрые тесты с большим количеством ActiveRecord в проекте

Tags: yii2, activerecord, юнит-тесты, codeception

Дано: Проект с большим количеством Active Record и большим количеством Foreign Keys между ними. Сейчас для тестирования в целях независимости тестов друг от друга каждый тест загружает в базу данных фикстуры.

В случае если тесту требуется пользователь он загрузит в базу данных фикстуру `UserFixture` и все зависимые фикстуры.

Проблемы:

- Количество зависимостей очень большое, в базу данных грузится не только фикстура пользователя, но ещё и ещё больше 10 зависимых фикстур.
- Такую загрузку в базу требует каждый тест.
- Обычно тестам нужен не пользователь, но даже в этом случае для корректной подготовки БД его необходимо загрузить, так как фикстура пользователя скорее всего будет являеться зависимостью.

Сейчас у меня **почти все** юнит тесты содержат фикстуры и обращаются к базе данных. Количество юнит-тестов стало большим и это начало доставлять проблемы.

Как лучше всего использовать фикстуры для тестов?

Я вижу два варианта:

- Загрузить фикстуры в базу данных один раз и в тестах вручную возвращать измененные значения назад к исходным. (Крайне тяжело, вариант сразу отпадает).
- В тестах готовить необходимые объекты Active Record, а базу данных использовать только для тестов которые вызывают `insert` или `update` в базу данных. (Приоритетный вариант, но не слишком накладно будет перед каждым тестом готовить необходимые модели?)

Как правильно писать тесты в контексте веб-разработки, где большая часть операций идет с использованием Active Record? Как добиться ускорения работы тестов?

Приведите пример как в вашем проекте организованы тестирование методов, которые используют Active Record.

Comment: Не по теме но для информации.NoSQL+Python серверное решение для БД. Tarantool лично меня очень порожает.

Comment: @Павел: непонятно, в хорошем или плохом смысле вас поражает это сочетание.

Answer (score 8):

Это довольно классическая проблема тестирования, и ее решение заключается в выкидывании зависимостей. Вы не должны тестировать базу данных, поэтому никакие фикстуры вам на самом деле не нужны вплоть до того момента, как вы подойдете к системному/интеграционному тестированию сервиса целиком. На уровне модульного тестирования вы тестируете одну конкретную feature с очень узкой областью видимости, где все внешние зависимости можно (и нужно) подменить на моки, которые не только освоодят вас от проблем с БД, но и ускорят тесты.
У вас скорее всего уже появился вопрос - что делать с теми местами, в которых напихано штук десять моделей, которые приходят через статические методы. По-хорошему этих мест вообще не должно быть: приложение должно делиться на слои, и слой базы данных должен без проблем подменяться в вышестоящих менеджерах бизнес-логики (хотя саму бизнес-логику в модульных тестах я бы не стал тестировать, отдав это все на откуп более высокоуровневым тестам).

Впрочем, с базой данных есть еще одно решение, которое я не устану пиарить - это Docker. Docker позволит вам сохранить базу данных в определенном состоянии и возвращать ее к нему же путем переподнятия контейнера; пул из десятка перезапускаемых контейнеров может предоставлять новую БД практически мгновенно. Впрочем, примерно то же самое можно сделать на основе SQLite.

Comment: SQLite не имеет внешних ключей, а вот с Docker идея звучит интересно. Я сейчас использую Vagrant, попробую покопаться с Docker. По поводу моков: к примеру есть метод, который, выполняя некоторые рассчеты, сохраняет 4-5 ActiveRecord со связями между ними. Для корректной работы нужно чтобы у моделей при сохранении устанавливались primary key. Я могу сделать моки на это, но это просто огромный объем подготовительный работы. Также что делать если в процессе работы метод идет через связи->к->другой->таблице. Придется мочить все эти методы. Разрабатывать строго соблюдая закон деметры?

Comment: метод не должен выполнять расчеты и работать с БД одновременно.

Comment: Есть публичная функция `saveCalculatedPrice`. Она поручает одному классу посчитать сумму и другому классу сохранить результат. Вполне нормальное поведение. Если протестировать те два класса по отдельности не составляет проблемы, то тестирование `saveCalculatedPrice` уже становится сложнее, так как надо подготовить два класса для его работы. Как справляться с задачами которые решаются не парой классов, а большим количеством? Назвать это интеграционными тестами? В таком случае где грань? `saveCalculatedPrice` является интеграционным тестом или нет? Можете посоветовать что почитать по теме?

Comment: @Onedev.Link почитать боюсь нет, конкретно `saveCalculatedPrice` я бы тестил на моках. Интеграционное подразумевает, что на приложение воздействуют снаружи, так что нет, это пока еще не оно (но никто не запрещает протестировать тот же самый кусок кода прямым запросом)

Comment: @Onedev.Link `saveCalculatedPrice` надо тестировать на моках. Расчет суммы выполняет один класс и это поведение протестировано в тестах этого класса. Сохранение выполняет другой класс и это поведение протестировано в его тестах. Задача функции `saveCalculatedPrice` поочередено обратиться к этим двум классам, вот эту задачу и надо тестировать. Сделать это можно только с помощью моков, иначе вы неизбежно будете повторно тестировать поведение уже протестированное в других местах и иметь дело с теми проблемами которые вы описываете в вопросе.

Comment: @Onedev.Link как вы делаете моки? вы пишете про это - _надо подготовить два класса для его работы_, выходит вы пишете моки сами? Если так, это действительно очень трудоемко, чтобы требовалось меньше рутинной работы посмотрите в сторону mock-фреймворков, например [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4).

Comment: @Onedev.Link почитать стоит _"Разработка через тестирование" Кента Бека_, если еще не читали. Это одна из классических книг по теме. Прочтение должно снять большинство вопросов. Пусть название вас не пугает, если вы вдруг не хотите писать код через тестирование. Если вы пишете тесты после кода, она вам тоже пригодится.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev Спасибо! По поводу тестирования `saveCalculatedPrice` на моках вы абсолютно правы. Кента Бека начал читать второй раз, думаю на этот раз в голове останется больше информации. Можете помочь ещё с вопросом что делать `с->такими->вызовами->в->тестируемом->методе`, в случае ActiveRecord? По идее такого нельзя допускать и нужно ограничиться только одним вызовом. Но это удобно сразу  переходить по связанным сущностям и в коде не появляются лишние методы. В контексте TDD будет ли правильным решением для ActiveRecord сделать исключение и использовать такие длинные вызовы?

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev Перенесите, пожалуйста, комментарии в ответ. Я хочу поделиться репутацией в награду за помощь.

Comment: @Onedev.Link По поводу вызова связанной сущности через длинную цепочку зависимостей, мне сложно сказать. Я не работал с yii и не знаю особенностей фреймворка. ДУмаю по этому поводу стоит создать отдельный вопрос с конкретным примером вызова. Так будет проще ответить и если кто-нибудь ответит - ответ не потеряется в комментариях.

Comment: @Onedev.Link перенес комментарии в ответ, плюс добавил там пару слов про интеграционные тесты

Answer (score 1):

Ответ состоит в том, что вы должны использовать моки вместо реального обращения к базе данных в каждом тесте. По сути это второй вариант решения, который вы предложили.

На вашем примере: пусть есть метод `saveCalculatedPrice`, который поручает одному классу посчитать сумму, а другому классу - сохранить ее в бд.

Этот метод надо тестировать на моках. Расчет суммы выполняет один класс и это поведение протестировано в тестах этого класса. Сохранение выполняет другой класс и это поведение протестировано в его тестах. Задача функции `saveCalculatedPrice` поочередено обратиться к этим двум классам, вот эту задачу и надо тестировать. Сделать это можно только с помощью моков, иначе вы неизбежно будете повторно тестировать поведение уже протестированное в других местах и иметь дело с теми проблемами которые вы описываете в вопросе.

По поводу накладности написания моков для тестов, вопрос в том как вы делаете моки. Если вы пишете все моки сами, то это действительно очень трудоемко, чтобы требовалось меньше рутинной работы посмотрите в сторону mock-фреймворков, например [phake](http://phake.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/).

Вообще, как советуют в соседнем ответе, я бы не тестировал работу с бд в юнит-тестах и оставил бы это на откуп интеграционным тестам. Вместо этого в юнит тестах везде где надо обратиться к реальной базе данных я бы подставлял мок.

Когда вы дойдете до написания интеграцинных тестов, вы будете тестировать ваше приложение на более высоком уровне, и вам скорее всего не потребуется готовить бд отдельно для каждого теста. Вместо этого лучше организовать тестирование следующим образом:

- создать тестовую бд
- поочередно выполнить на ней все интеграционные тесты

То есть интеграционные тесты будут выполняться в среде приближенной к реальной среде, в которой выполняется приложение.